# How to get same values for merge cells? laravel import

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have a problem encounter, in which Laravel import returns null for merge cells.

Here is my code *(I tried collection also but same it returns null)*:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    dump($row[0]);
}
```

---

Here is my excel file look like *(2-A to 11-A are merged)*

[image]

When I try to `dump` it returns null for other rows.

[image]